# How to calculate cumulative product in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

In python calculate cumulative product, i can use **numpy.cumprod**

```
>>> a = [2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> numpy.cumprod(a)
[2, 6, 24, 120]
# this is result i want.  [2, 3, 4, 5] => [2, 2*3, 2*3*4, 2*3*4*5] => [2, 6, 24, 120]
```

But i don't know how to write sql in **CLICKHOUSE**
Table A:

```
row rate
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

The column rate is result i want, how to use **CLICKHOUSE SQL** statement achieve.

```
row rate
1    2
2    6
3    24
4    120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way. I would add (implement) a new function in CH arrayCumProd

```
SELECT
    i, pow(2,arraySum(z->log2(z),n))
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ig,
        arrayMap( i -> arraySlice(ng, 1, i), arrayEnumerate(groupArray(x) AS ng) as ig) xx
    FROM ( SELECT arrayJoin([2, 3, 4, 5]) AS x )
)
ARRAY JOIN
    ig AS i,
    xx AS n

┌─i─┬─pow(2, arraySum(lambda(tuple(z), log2(z)), n))─┐
│ 1 │                                              2 │
│ 2 │                                              6 │
│ 3 │                                             24 │
│ 4 │                             119.99999999999994 │
└───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

hm, It seems I over-complicated it.

```
SELECT x FROM
(
    SELECT
        arrayMap(i -> pow(2,i), arrayCumSum(groupArray(log2(x)))) z
    FROM ( SELECT arrayJoin([2, 3, 4, 5]) AS x )
)
ARRAY JOIN z as x
```

Answer (score 2):

I just extend the answer by @Denis Zhuravlev.

CH doesn't have the dedicated function to calculate cumulative multiplication (or any arbitrary math operator besides addition), moreover, the exist functions cannot be applied to get require result because of 'cumulative'-nature this calculation.

So that need to transform multiplication to addition using logarithms:

> log<sub>a</sub> x*y = log<sub>a</sub> x + log<sub>a</sub> y
>
> x*y = a<sup>(log<sub>a</sub> x + log<sub>a</sub> y)</sup>

```sql
SELECT r.1.1 row, r.1.2 rate, r.2 value, round(r.2, 2) rounded_value
FROM (
  SELECT 
    groupArray((row, rate, rate_log)) data,
    arrayMap(log -> exp10(log), arrayCumSum(data_item -> data_item.3, data)) rate_cumulative_values,
    arrayJoin(arrayZip(data, rate_cumulative_values)) r  
  FROM (
    SELECT row, rate, log10(rate) AS rate_log
    FROM (
      /* emulate the origin dataset */
      SELECT data.1 row, data.2 rate
      FROM (SELECT arrayJoin([
        (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5),
        (5, 1), (6, 0), (7, -1)]) AS data))
    ORDER BY row));
/*
┌─row─┬─rate─┬──────────────value─┬─rounded_value─┐
│   1 │    2 │                  2 │             2 │
│   2 │    3 │                  6 │             6 │
│   3 │    4 │ 23.999999999999993 │            24 │
│   4 │    5 │ 119.99999999999996 │           120 │
│   5 │    1 │ 119.99999999999996 │           120 │
│   6 │    0 │                  0 │             0 │
│   7 │   -1 │                nan │           nan │
└─────┴──────┴────────────────────┴───────────────┘
*/
```

---

The same logic can be applied to calculation cumulative division:

> x/y = a<sup>(log<sub>a</sub> x - log<sub>a</sub> y)</sup>

Cumulative division:

```sql
SELECT r.1.1 row, r.1.2 rate, r.2 value, round(r.2, 2) rounded_value
FROM (
  SELECT 
    groupArray((row, rate, rate_log)) data,
    arrayMap(log -> exp10(log), arrayCumSum((data_item, index) -> index = 1 ? data_item.3 : - data_item.3, data, arrayEnumerate(data))) rate_cumulative_values,
    arrayJoin(arrayZip(data, rate_cumulative_values)) r  
  FROM (
    SELECT row, rate, log10(rate) AS rate_log
    FROM (
      /* emulate the origin dataset */
      SELECT data.1 row, data.2 rate
      FROM (SELECT arrayJoin([
        (1, 100), (2, 2), (3, 10), (4, 2)]) AS data))
    ORDER BY row));
/*
┌─row─┬─rate─┬──────────────value─┬─rounded_value─┐
│   1 │  100 │                100 │           100 │
│   2 │    2 │  49.99999999999999 │            50 │
│   3 │   10 │  4.999999999999999 │             5 │
│   4 │    2 │ 2.4999999999999996 │           2.5 │
└─────┴──────┴────────────────────┴───────────────┘
*/
```